# How use a random key in json in multidimensional array

Tags: json, random

I need get random key to select different response.

I have: `response.data.players["11"].name` and i need random value instead of 11 because all keys are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the Object.keys method in Javascript. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```js
var keys = Object.keys(response.data.players);
var player = response.data.players[keys[0]];
```

If you want to get a random player you can use this code:

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

var keys = Object.keys(response.data.players);
var player = response.data.players[keys[getRandomInt(keys.length)]];
```

Comment: Ok, and how get random?